# Concatenate 2 arrays in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, python-3.x, toml, pyproject.toml

I'm giving a shot to the `pyproject.toml` file, and I'm stuck on this simple task. Consider the following optional dependencies:

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
style = ["black", "codespell", "isort", "flake8"]
test = ["pytest", "pytest-cov"]
all = ["black", "codespell", "isort", "flake8", "pytest", "pytest-cov"]
```

Is there a way to avoid copy/pasting all the optional-dep in the `all` key? Is there a way to do `all = style + test` at least?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such feature directly in the [toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/77) markup.

However, there is a tricky way to do this in Python packaging by depending on yourself:

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
style = ["black", "codespell", "isort", "flake8"]
test = ["pytest", "pytest-cov"]
all = ["myproject[style]", "myproject[test]"]
```

[Source](https://discuss.python.org/t/pyproject-toml-optional-dependencies-redundancy-aka-dry-extras/8428/6?u=wim):

> Circular dependency is a feature that Python packaging is explicitly designed to allow, so it works and should continue to work.