# Python: create logfile in toml with timestamp in the name

Tags: python, toml

im trying to create a log_file with thte timestmap formatted in the name in my toml-file.
I have this code:

```
loge_file = "..log/pytest_" + {timestamp} + ".log"
```

but seeing the syntax i know it's wrong. When i run my code i get the error:

```
ValueError: Found tokens after a closed string. Invalid TOML
```

How can i fix this code?

Comment: try this - loge_file = f"..log/pytest_{timestamp}.log"

Comment: i have tried that but that isnt working in a toml file.

Comment: why are you using a TOML file for logging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate 2 arrays in pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398203/concatenate-2-arrays-in-pyproject-toml)